# How to pass php variable in window.location javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass the php variable inside the window.location javascript this is my php code and i am unable to do that.

```
echo '<script>location.href = "reportConsumption.php?creategenReport="'.$genid.'"&sDate="'.$startdate.'"&eDate="'.$enddate;</script>';
```

Comment: Why not just use `header("Location: $url")`?

Comment: header is not working it is not redirecting so i am using location.href

Comment: If `header("Location: $url")` is not working then i am sure `location.href` will not work also. BTW try once:- `echo '<script>location.href ="reportConsumption.php?creategenReport='.$genid.'&sDate='.$startdate.'&eDate='.$enddate.'"</script>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing your quote in JS

```
echo '<script>location.href = "reportConsumption.php?creategenReport="'.$genid.'"&sDate="'.$startdate.'"&eDate="'.$enddate;</script>';
```

Should be

```
 echo '<script>location.href = "reportConsumption.php?creategenReport='.$genid.'&sDate='.$startdate.'&eDate='.$enddate.'</script>';
```

This will cause an error in JS on the client side, you could see this by pressing `f12` and looking in the console log in the browser debugger.  Your source code will look like this

```
 <script>location.href = "reportConsumption.php?creategenReport="35"&sDate="...

 //where this is a quoted block
 "reportConsumption.php?creategenReport="
 //and this is just chilling in space
 35
 //and then a new quoted block, etc.
 "&sDate="
```

And you had this other (php syntax error) issue I took the liberty of fixing.

```
 .$enddate;</script>';
```

Just in PHP you can redirect with

```
  header("Location: $url");
```

But you have to be sure of 2 things:

1. You do not output "Anything" not even a line return before calling `header`
2. You call `exit();` immediately after it.  If  you don't PHP will continue to execute the current script after it executes the redirect.  Which is probably not desirable.

Comment: lets suppose i have this kind of situation then?
  echo '<script>window.open("reportConsumption.php?creategenReport='.$genid.'&sDate='.$startdate.'&eDate='.$enddate.'",'_blank');</script>';

Comment: Then you should probably double quote this `'_blank'` like `"_blank"`, basically this is the opposite issue where `$enddate.'",'_blank`  specifically `.'",'` closes the block.  PS you can do inline code format with the backtic ` its aka ~ tilde

Comment: man it really worked but the problem is that it is showing popup blocked can i resolve it via code

Comment: I would post it as a separate question.  Comments is not really the place to handle it, just saying.

Comment: i am not been able to post question before 60 mins

Comment: That sux, I only ever asked like 2 maybe 3 questions... didn't know that was a thing.  Well I would suggest updating this question with the relevant information.  you can do ##UPDATE for bold

Answer (score 2):

try to set quotation marks

```
echo '<script>location.href = "reportConsumption.php?creategenReport='.$genid.'&sDate='.$startdate.'&eDate='.$enddate.'"</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the double quotes too early. It should be close at the end of the URL. So you have a syntax error in your JavaScript:

```
echo '<script>location.href = "reportConsumption.php?creategenReport='.$genid.'&sDate='.$startdate.'&eDate='.$enddate.'";</script>';
```

Or separate using a variable to be more clear:

```
$url = 'reportConsumption.php?creategenReport='.$genid.'&sDate='.$startdate.'&eDate='.$enddate;
echo '<script>location.href = "'.$url.'";</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use double quote around the values for GET param

```
  echo '<script>location.href = "reportConsumption.php?creategenReport='.$genid. 
          '&sDate='.$startdate.'&eDate='. $enddate .'"';</script>';
```